# All voltage directed to pin 3 when multiple pins are set to out put

Tags: pins

I just finished testing a haptic device at university, and when I took it home I got the joy of finding the device not working. Here's what I can trace the problem to: when multiple pins are set to output (pin 2~11), pin 3 writes constantly to high and there is nothing I can do to make it stop.

Using a blinker program one pin at a time produces no problems, however when I run a blinker program that cycles through all pins, pin 3 is set to constant high. My actual code is similar in function but more complex. This program below though gets the same error.

```
void setup()
{
  for (int c =2; c<12; c++){
    pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{  
  for (int c =2; c<12 ; c++){
     digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
     delay(100);
     digitalWrite(c, LOW);
     delay(100);
  }  
}
```

Is this a sign my arduino died? My device had been working for weeks on my prior code with no problem (and no updates).

Comment: That's a symptom that maybe just the MCU pin 3 is damaged. But it would help to know how your initial circuit (the one that may have caused the damage) and the blinking circuits were wired. Could you please post some schematics?

Comment: If your Arduino board holds the MCU in a socket (like the Uno), and you have a spare ATmega laying around, you can try and replace the MCU and test it again with your blinking program to see if pin 3 makes the LED blink. Just to check, you do have current limiting resistors between your IO pins and your LEDs, and you aren't (and weren't) drawing more than 20mA from each pin and 200mA overall from your MCU, right?

Comment: That's all assuming you're using ATmega's...

Comment: Or, if you don't have a socketed ATmega or an extra one lying around, you may want to acquire a whole other arduino and test with that to see if you can replicate the behavior. You don't necessarily need to buy the exact same model as the one you're experiencing the problem with, but that would be the best way to identify a problem with your code running on your original board.

Comment: Could you tell what you have plugged to each of pins 2 to 11? You may get erratic behavior (if not worse) if you source or sink too much current through many pins altogether (Arduino total current limits).

Comment: My wiring for testing = using a voltmeter.
The wiring for the actual project is running an array of electromagnets through motorbridges with never more than one pin on at a time. The set-up has worked for weeks with no bugs. It is bread-boarded, so I figured that was the problem at first. However the behavior is reproducible when only connect to a voltmeter.

Comment: It is an Arduino Uno, and I replaced the chip using a similar Atmega chip but not the same (ATMEGA328-PU 1135 to a ATMEGA328-PU 1036). The replacement has a different firmware (Duemilanove I think). I could get the blinker test program to run without a hitch, but the new chip doesn't handle serial communications well (something my project relies on) so I couldn't get it to work with my original code.

Comment: Here's the actual project [here](http://www.e-alexander.net/magic_slippers.php), if that will help anything.

Comment: The 4-digit number is a date code. You replaced it with the same chip made almost a year earlier.

Comment: imho, breadboards are for only the first moments of a design. Please please please get and use a sensor shield: https://www.google.com/search?q=sensor+shield Fritzing is also invaluable for illustrating circuits.

Comment: @e2r2i2k2 Do you use your voltmeter directly between the pin and the ground? It's not the right way to measure a voltage, you should at least put a resistor between the pin and the ground.

Comment: @e2r2i2k2 did you flash the UNO bootloader onto the ATmega after you replaced it? By the way, is there a reason why you replaced it?

Comment: @jfpoilpret I replaced the chip for debugging. And yes, I was using a current limiting resistor for volt testing. I'm short of a one part to put together a bootloader installer set-up, so I'll try that when the part comes.

Comment: If you require a current limiting resistor for voltage testing then your DMM is damaged :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a dead chip. Try getting a new ATmega chip for the Arduino (easily found online for ~$5) and see if that fixes it.